# Cannot close progressDialog after AsyncTask is complete

Tags: android

I first show a progressDialog and then kick off a Thread from my Activity to get a url. I pass a handler also from Activity to the Thread's request listener, and then when the Thread is complete, control is passed to a requestListener, in the requestListener, I call an asynctask to get another URL, finally when this is complete, I call the handler to show a success Dialog on the original Activity.

The success dialog shows fine, which means that the handler really is running on the UI thread, but I cannot get a reference back to the progressDialog.

I've tried : passing the pDialog to the Handler, referring to it from a global application state, setting it as a static member of Activity.

But the progress dialog is always null....what is going on??? Why can I show the success dialog from the Handler, but not get a handle to the progressDialog

I have solved this issue...

---

I had:

```
public void showProg() {
  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
  pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
  pDialog.show();
}
```

and when I move the contents of this method outside to the same place I was calling it...every works.....what is up???

Comment: Did you try passing the pDialog to the AsyncTask along with the handler? The handler is not a path back to other UI elements. As long as all this is in the same activity, you don't really need a global activity state. As to it being a static member of your activity, I suspect a coding error. Perhaps you could post your code.

Comment: its really...wierd see my solution

Comment: Can you add the solution as an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.